# Solve the differential equation $y'=\frac{y+1}{y-1}$ by separating variables

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$y'=\frac{y+1}{y-1}$

Solve the differential equation by separating variables and give the solution in an implicit form.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y+1}{y-1}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow dy = \left (\frac{y+1}{y-1} \right )dx$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \left (\frac{y-1}{y+1}\right) dy = dx$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \int{\frac{y-1}{y+1} dy} = \int{dx}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \int{\frac{y+1-2}{y+1} dy} = \int{dx}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \int{\frac{y+1}{y+1}-\frac{2}{y+1} dy} = \int{dx}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow y - 2\ln|y+1| = x + C $$

This is what I got right now.

I literally don't know if this is correct and especially whether this is also good in the implicit form.
Normally you can always check the solution by filling it in, but I wouldn't know how to do that in this case.

Comment: You can check your solution by differentiating both sides to see if $y' = \frac{y+1}{y-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculus is correct :
$$x(y)=y-2\ln|y+1|+c$$
You can check it :
$$x'=1-\frac{2}{y+1}$$
$$y'=\frac{1}{x'}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{y+1}}=\frac{y+1}{y-1}\quad\text{is OK.}$$
For information :

The calculus of the inverse function $y(x)$ requires a special function, namely the Lambert-W function : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html
$$y(x)=-1-2\:W\left(C\:e^{-x/2}\right)$$
$C$ is an arbitrary constant.